How to determine the single-qubit gate if we know an initial and corresponding final state
HOW TO FIND A QUANTUM GATE IF WE KNOW THE INITIAL AND FINAL SINGLE QUBIT STATES? I tried thinking by using projection vectors like ket 0 goes to ket I, then we can take the ket 0 bra I, but the quantum gate I am getting is not transforming ket 0 to ket I correctly.

A unitary preserves inner products and, in particular, orthogonality. So, let's say you know that $U$ achieves the single-qubit transformation
$$
|\psi\rangle\longrightarrow|\phi\rangle.
$$
Then you also know that it transforms a state that is orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$ into a state that is orthogonal to $|\phi\rangle$. In a single-qubit system, these states are uniquely defined (up to a global phase which is, nevertheless, important in what we're about to do because it becomes a relative phase). Let's call them $|\psi^\perp\rangle$ and $|\phi^\perp\rangle$.
So, now we can write down
$$
U=|\phi\rangle\langle\psi|+e^{i\phi}|\phi^\perp\rangle\langle\psi^\perp|
$$
where the $\phi$ is that global/relative phase I mentioned before. You can check that this is unitary:
$$
U^\dagger U=|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|+|\psi^\perp\rangle\langle\psi^\perp|=I
$$
and that it performs the desired transformation
$$
U|\psi\rangle=|\phi\rangle.
$$
Example: let $|\psi\rangle=|0\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle=(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. Then, up to global phases, it must be that $|\psi^\perp=|1\rangle$ and $|\phi^\perp\rangle=(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. Thus,
$$
U=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & e^{i\phi} \\
1 & -e^{i\phi}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Obviously, $U$ is not uniquely determined. If you put $\phi=0$, you'll get the usual Hadamard. With $\phi=\pi$, you'll get $\sqrt{Y}$.
